# How can I prevent the cell from being run if some conditions are satisfied in IPython shell?

Tags: python, ipython

Assume I run the following code in IPython interactive shell:

```py
def pre_run_cell(info):
    raise RuntimeError("please don't run")

get_ipython().events.register("pre_run_cell", pre_run_cell)
```

Then, each time before a cell is run, `pre_run_cell()` is called.

However, even though the `pre_run_cell()` raises an error, the cell is still executed:

```py
In [3]: 1
Error in callback <function pre_run_cell at 0x7f6eae1a6020> (for pre_run_cell), with arguments args (<ExecutionInfo object at 7f6eae4346d0, raw_cell="1" store_history=True silent=False shell_futures=True cell_id=None>,),kwargs {}:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[1], line 2, in pre_run_cell(info)
      1 def pre_run_cell(info):
----> 2         raise RuntimeError("please don't run")

RuntimeError: please don't run
Out[3]: 1
```

How can I check some condition and possibly prevent the cell from running **before running each cell**? (or from within `pre_run_cell` hook)

I don't see anything in the [documentation of `pre_run_cell`)](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config/callbacks.html#pre-run-cell) with such a feature.

Answer (score 0):

One possible option is to use an [AST transformer](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config/inputtransforms.html#ast-transformations) and just delete the whole body. You need to find some way to link the `pre_run_cell` callback and the AST transformer.

For example:

```py
from typing import Any
import ast
import random

class ASTTransformerDeleteEverything:
    def visit(self, node)->Any:
        assert isinstance(node, ast.Module), node
        get_ipython().ast_transformers.remove(self)  % <<< this line ensures that the AST transformer is only executed for this cell
        node.body.clear()
        return node

def pre_run_cell(info)->None:
    try:
        print("quotient =", 1/random.randint(0, 1))
    except:
        get_ipython().ast_transformers.append(ASTTransformerDeleteEverything())
        raise
```

Then, to use it:

```py
In [2]: get_ipython().events.register("pre_run_cell", pre_run_cell)

In [3]: 1
quotient = 1.0
Out[3]: 1

In [4]: 1
Error in callback <function pre_run_cell at 0x77e8d5708540> (for pre_run_cell), with arguments args (<ExecutionInfo object at 77e8d571a5d0, raw_cell="1" store_history=True silent=False shell_futures=True cell_id=None>,),kwargs {}:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ZeroDivisionError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
File <ipython-input-1-773f8b1dbe7a>:14, in pre_run_cell(info)
     12 def pre_run_cell(info)->None:
     13     try:
---> 14         print("quotient =", 1/random.randint(0, 1))
     15     except:
     16         get_ipython().ast_transformers.append(ASTTransformerDeleteEverything())

ZeroDivisionError: division by zero
```